# If a sequence is bounded, does its weak limit happen to be bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $(H, \|\cdot\|)$ be a Hilbert space and let $(f_n)_n$ be a bounded sequence in $H$, i.e. there exists $C>0$ such that
$$\|f_n\|\le C \quad\forall n.$$
Let $f$ denote the weak limit of $f_n$.

Does one can conclude that $f$ is bounded in $H$? If it is true, is it bounded with the same constant $C$?

I am trying to find a proof (or a counterexample) on this matter on my textbook, but I can not find.

Does anyone have a reference? Or better, anyone could please help me in proving the result?

Comment: You even have $\|f\| \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \|f_n\|$ if you tweak peak-a-boo's answer a little and remember that $\|g\| = \|T_g\|$ if $T_g$ is the operator $h \mapsto \langle g, h\rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re asking whether $\|f\|<\infty$, the answer is trivially a yes, because norms are by definition finite.

For the second question, yes. Notice that by Cauchy-Schwarz,
\begin{align}
|\langle f_n,f\rangle|&\leq \|f_n\|\cdot\|f\|\leq C\|f\|.
\end{align}
Since $f_n\to f$ weakly, we can take the limit $n\to\infty$ on the LHS to get $\|f\|^2=\langle f,f\rangle\leq C\|f\|$. Hence, $\|f\|\leq C$ (really this is a two case argument: if $\|f\|=0$, the inequality is trivial, and otherwise we divide both sides of the previous inequality by $\|f\|$).

---

**Edit:**

@Bruno B’s comment is a good one, so I think I might as well mention the generalization to Banach spaces.

> **Theorem.**
>
> Let $X$ be any Banach space.
>
> - If $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $X$ which converges weakly to some $x\in X$, then $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is norm-bounded and $\|x\|\leq \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|$.
> - If $\{\xi_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $X^*$ which converges in the weak* topology to some $\xi\in X^*$, then $\{\xi_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is norm-bounded and $\|\xi\|\leq \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\|\xi_n\|$.

The proof uses that the inclusion $\iota:X\to X^{**}$ is an isometry (using Hahn-Banach), and the *uniform boundedness principle* (Banach-Steinhaus theorem). For reflexive Banach spaces (e.g Hilbert spaces), the second is a corollary of the first.